# Get available audio sources

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

Is there a way to get a list of available audio sources implemented on the device running the application? I want this to allow the user to choose from these however the API does not seem to have anything for this. It just falls back to default if the specified audio source is not available. So it would be a waste to display them to the user when they might not even work.

Or is it guaranteed that all android devices implement a certain number of these sources?

Thanks in advance.